# What might be causing LDAP to refuse connections from some but not all sources? (not firewall)

Tags: amazon-web-services, openldap, centos7

I'm migrating servers to new infrastructure and have to set up LDAP again.  It's not being used to access the server, rather as a repository of users from our website to be accessed by our BI platform.

LDAP is up and running and I can connect and bind using LDAP Administrator from my computer in the office, no worries.

What I can't do is get Drupal (on the same server) or YellowFin (java application on different server same cluster) to bind.  I'm pretty sure they're connecting, but not binding, and I'm using exactly the same credentials in all three places.

The only error I get from Drupal is:

```
Failed to bind to server. ldap error #82 Success
```

From Yellowfin there's a bit more information (I think; identifying data redacted):

```
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:DEBUG (LDAPUtil:createConnection) - Opening connection to xx.xx.xx.xx on port 636
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:DEBUG (JNDILDAPProvider:authenticate) - Connecting: ldaps://xx.xx.xx.xx:636
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:DEBUG (JNDILDAPProvider:authenticate) - User: cn=admin,dc=xxxxxxxxxxx,dc=com,dc=au
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:ERROR (LDAPUtil:createConnection) - LDAP authentication failed
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:ERROR (LDAPUtil:createConnection) - LDAP authentication failed
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:ERROR (LDAPUtil:testConnection) - LDAP connection failed
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:26:DEBUG (DSTCache:getJavaTimeZoneID) - Invalid TimeZoneCode passed. Value was ASIA/ABU_DHABI
  YF:2015-05-08 01:54:27:DEBUG (MIImageAction:execute) - MIImageAction entered
```

I'm wondering if the timezone error is an issue, maybe?

The slapd service is listening for all IPs on port 636, relevant `netstat` results:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:636             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9150/slapd
tcp6       0      0 :::636                  :::*                    LISTEN      9150/slapd
```

We're using AWS and I've tried opening the security group (firewall) completely on port 636 with no results.

ldap.conf looks like this:

```
# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=intermedium,dc=com,dc=au
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666
URI ldap://127.0.0.1 ldaps://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never

TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/openldap/certs
  TLSCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca-bundle
  TLSCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt
  TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.key
TLS_REQCERT allow
REFERRALS off

# Turning this off breaks GSSAPI used with krb5 when rdns = false
#SASL_NOCANON   on
```

slapd.conf looks like this:

```
# OpenLDAP server configuration
# see 'man slapd' for additional information

# Where the server will run (-h option)
# - ldapi:/// is required for on-the-fly configuration using client tools
#   (use SASL with EXTERNAL mechanism for authentication)
# - default: ldapi:/// ldap:///
# - example: ldapi:/// ldap://127.0.0.1/ ldap://10.0.0.1:1389/ ldaps:///
SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldaps:///"

# Any custom options
#SLAPD_OPTIONS=""

# Keytab location for GSSAPI Kerberos authentication
#KRB5_KTNAME="FILE:/etc/openldap/ldap.keytab"
```

I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: what implementation of LDAP you are using? 82 is not a standard error code in RFC. If you are using AD, make sure time difference between client and LDAP is not too big (default < 5min).

Comment: Thanks strongline, we're using openldap from the yum repository in CentOS 7.  Drupal and LDAP are running on the same server so the time difference should be nil between them.  The YellowFin server is on the same AWS subnet so it too should have the same timezone as they were spun up exactly the same way.

Comment: I wonder (not very confidently) if it's a problem with the client's verifying the TLS certificate?

Comment: For OpenLDAP, its official page provide below

 "C.1.25. ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (82)
Apparently not having forward and reverse DNS entries for the LDAP server can result in this error."

If we can read it literally, then we should make sure we have both A and PTR for LDAP server. - I am not an expert on OpenLDAP, so I will see what others have to say besides DNS records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to @strongline and @Craig Miskell for pointing me in a direction, in the end it was two different errors which I will put here in case someone else finds this useful.

### Drupal:

The bind was failing because the source site had Blowfish encryption enabled, and the destination server did not have the php-mcrypt mod installed, even though I updated the password it was still trying to use Blowfish encryption for the bind password.  Installing php-mcrypt fixed this.

### YellowFin (Java):

YellowFin needed the LDAP server's certificate and chain in a Java Keystore.  To fix, find the or make a certificate for the LDAP server and follow the instructions on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/1394872).

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the Timezone issue with the Java app, don't let Kava determine its own Timezone on Linux. Use TZ instead. I've blogged about this further at http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2014/09/dont-let-java-on-linux-determine-its.html